# Excel VBA replace with function but leave numbers

Tags: excel, vba, replace, ms-office

I want to replace Telephone numbers in the format +XX-XX-XXX XX XX with the same number in this format +XX (XX) XXX XX XX. I have a Find/Replace makro that almost works:

```
        Cells.Find(What:="+??-??-", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Cells.Replace What:="+??-??-", Replacement:="+?? (??) ", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
```

The problem now is that the numbers turn out in this format: +?? (??) XXX XX XX.
Is there a way in VBA to say I want to replace it in this format but leave these spaces (the +XX and the (XX) as they were? Because the way I did it just replaces everything with EXACTLY what I defined in Replacement:.
Or maybe there's a way I can temporarily save the numbers in the position where the ?? wildcards are and add them back in in the Replacement: section?

Would be cool if someone could help a noob out

Answer (score 2):

Try this way, please:

```
 Dim x As String, y As String, ar As Variant
  x = "+XX-XX-XXX XX XX"
  ar = Split(x, "-")
  y = ar(0) & " (" & ar(1) & ") " & ar(2)
  MsgBox y
```

Comment: Fine and complete answer :+) - Hypothetical reflexion  if there were additional array tokens with same delimiter `"-"`, then you could limit the number of tokens to three via 3rd argument `ar = Split(x, "-", 3)` and replace delimiter(s) in `ar(2)` only.

Comment: @T.M.: Yes, I sometime use the third (`limit`) argument, but now it was not the case...

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here's a worksheet function:

```
=TEXT(SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(1/(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(20),1)+1)),MID(A1,SEQUENCE(20),1)*10^MMULT(-(SEQUENCE(20)<TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(20))),-ISNUMBER(1/(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(20),1)+1))))),"+00 (00) 000 00 00")
```

The function first removes all of the non-numbers from the string, and then formats the resulting number with the `TEXT` function.

If you have an older version of excel and do not have the `SEQUENCE` function, you can create a named formula instead to generate a similar array of numbers.  Replace `SEQUENCE(20)` with `seq` where

```
seq Refers To:  =ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1,1):INDEX($A:$A,20,1))
```

You can use a similar algorithm in VBA where you first remove all of the non-digits, and then create a formatted string with the vba `Format` function.